# Implementing a HomeScreen-like horizontally scrollable widget?

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, homescreen

Most Android devices feature a home screen which you can scroll horizontally by dragging (there're others that have a grid-like 2d scrolling feature too, but I'm only interested in horizontal scrolling).

Could someone shed some light for me on how this might be achieved?

First I was thinking about using a custom ViewFlipper. I could attach proper sliding animations for it, but it's not exactly the same thing. On the home screen, the "amount of sliding" depends on how far you've dragged your finger on the screen. Animations are fire-and-forget things, I can't stop them midway.

Any ideas?

Here's a video about the desired behaviour: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGdWM2TQNSo&feature=player_detailpage#t=104s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the way Android's stock Launcher app does this here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java

You're primarily interested in the `onTouchEvent`, `onInterceptTouchEvent`, and `computeScroll` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Google released the compatibility pack with some new UI Elements, which you can download via SDK Manager.

- put the .jar file located in `sdkfolder/extras/compatibility` in your build path.
- now you can use a class called `ViewPager` which behaves like the Android Homescreen.

Or, if you are using Eclipse and ADT plugin v12 or higher, just right click your project, choose "Android Tools" and then "add compatibility package".